# How do I read a string of numbers and symbols as Math?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm writing a calculator and I want to know how to read a string written from a prompt such as 2 + 4 x 2 - 2 as a math problem, And set a variable as 10

Comment: You are looking for a parser. What language are you developing in?

Comment: @Timtro I assume JavaScript, since that is what the question is tagged as.

Comment: Note that the result is 8

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Quite right you are. ^Facepalm.^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) `.eval()` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/hxn6umd8/):

```
var result = math.eval('2 + 4 * 2 - 2'); // result = 8
```

Note that you have to replace 4 x 2 with 4 * 2, as 'x' is parsed as a parameter, and not as a sign for multiplication.

Comment: I tried that, But it just stops at that, And it gets an error at it.

Comment: Because you have to replace 4 x 2 with multiplication sign * .